# R , changing the class of few columns in a data frame

Tags: r, class, sum, sapply

I want to sum each column in iris data frame with sapply. But an error occurs because species class is factor.

How can I make the class of that column to numeric ?

Comment: [Did you search?](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+factor+to+numeric)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it'd make any sense to convert the column 'Species' to numeric. However, you could do that with

```
df<-iris
df$Species<-as.numeric(df$Species)
sapply(df, sum)
```

If you don't need to summarise the column 'Species', you can just:

```
sapply(iris[,-5], sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is probably to just exclude the `Species` column:

```
colSums(iris[, -5])
```

If you converted it, how would you interpret the sum?

Comment: True. You can't interpret anything. Excluding the species column would be ideal. But I wanted to learn how to convert the class of a column.